# I want to ssh to a linux computer, but i don't know the public IP address, How can I do it?

Tags: linux, ssh

I helped a friend install a printer server on linux using CUPS since windows driver suddenly changed and they couldn't access the printer anymore.

Something happened (maybe someone unplugged the printer?) and when I went to his office to check, I found out that the printer was "paused".

I resumed the printer and everything works.

BUT

I don't want to go back to him if something similar happens again.

I want to be able to ssh into his computer from my home

BUT

He has a dynamic public IP.

What can I do?

I have a Linux server with a static public IP that I can use

(is there something like an "active request for ssh" were I tell my friend computer to ask my server every x minutes if he wants to establish an ssh connection?
this way it is the computer that creates the connection to my server, which has a static ip)

Thank you
:)

Comment: Use a dynamic DNS service like dyn.com, no-ip.com, etc.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.